# How to connect to cctv using p2p?

Tags: android, flutter, security, p2p, live-streaming

I just wanna create an app that displays the live cctv through nvr using p2p connection but I can't get any details about what is the data I am gonna get so I can handle. It is the first time for me to use p2p connection and dealing with cctv cameras.

My question is how this data should look like I am not gonna mention a certain company but for the majority of them how this should be?

I am using flutter/dart. I tried searching for docs but what I get is only apps to do this and I wanna know the mechanism.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to decode the video stream and display the images on the screen. You can try `video_player` or low-level library such as `flutter_ffmpeg` inorder to decode the video stream and display it on the screen.